# Issue with ODI studio 11g

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I installed ODI Studio version 11.1.1.9 on windows 8 with JDK 1.8 and connected to remote ODI repository which is sitting on oracle 11.1.1.6.

I have no issues with creating interfaces and few objects. But when I tried to use ODI tools like `odisendemail`, `odiftpget`,  etc. in a ODI package, the first time I could see the properties and use them.

Later when I reopen the same package I was not able to select the ODI tool being used to see the properties again.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

ODI 11g doesn't support that JDK.
If you look at [System Requirements and Supported Platforms for Oracle Data Integrator 11gR1 (11.1.1.9.0)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integration/odi-11gr1certmatrix-11-1-1-9-0-2541436.xls) you will see that `ODI Studio UI does not support JDK 7` (nor any higher) which means:

- JDK 6 (1.6.0_35+) for Studio client
- JDK 7 (1.7.0_80+) for Agent.

Personally I think you might be best installing latest JDK 6 for both…

Comment: @user5297374: can you _Accept_ the answer then?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but now my challenging is to find JDK 6 for Mac os. I tried on oracle.com and google. Can someone help on this.

Comment: To install legacy JDK try the link from Apple support: [JDK 6 for Mac OS X](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572). If this solves your problem - can you be fair and finally **Accept** this answer?